# How to retrieve an image from an ImageView and store it in an Sqlite Database in Android?

Tags: android, sqlite, imageview

I have an ImageView in my activity.xml file. I am setting an Image in it which is retrieved from the server. I want to insert this picture from the ImageView into my Sqlite Database. can anyone explain to me how to do it? My table in Sqlite is as such `me ( fbId LONG PRIMARY KEY,fbname TEXT,fbuserid INTEGER,fbpic BLOB,ph TEXT,email TEXT)` Please tell me step by step as I am new to Databases.
I ahve added the following code bUt an error on insert i.e insert is undefined

```
 Bitmap photo = ((BitmapDrawable)v.getDrawable()).getBitmap();
    ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    photo.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, bos);
    byte[] bArray = bos.toByteArray();
    Databasehandler db =new Databasehandler(this);    
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();         
    values.put("image", bArray);            
    db.insert("image" , null, values);
```

Comment: what problems do you you have with that?

Comment: I don't know how to retrieve the image from the imageview and insert into the db

Comment: Drawable getDrawable()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQLITE data base cannot be used to store Image files directly. However the options you have are following:

1. Save the image that you received to SD card. May be create a separate folder in which you will store all the images. Then  Create a column imagePath in your table structure and save the path of the image to this column.

   Rendering: Here you will fetch the corresponding path from the DB, check if the file Exists at that path(might have been deleted by the user), and if found, get Stream from the file write it to a bitmap  and associate it to the required container.
2. Convert the bitmap received to a BASE64 String. Store this as String to the Data Base.

   Rendering: Here you will have to convert the BASE64 back to Bitmap and associate it to the required container.

Answer (score 3):

Get bitmap of the image view using:

```
Bitmap photo = ((BitmapDrawable)image.getDrawable()).getBitmap();
```

Create byte array of the bitmap:

```
ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
photo.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, bos);
byte[] bArray = bos.toByteArray();
```

Then you can save data in table using following way.

```
db = YourDBHelper.getInstance(ctx).getWritableDatabase();    
ContentValues values = new ContentValues();         
values.put("image", bArray);            
db.insert(TABLE_NAME , null, values);
```

Comment: Please check my code. i cannot use the insert method

Comment: What's issue your fetching. Please mention exception.

Answer (score 0):

**Save it on sdcard and path of sdcard on sqlite database**

```
   Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable)image.getDrawable()).getBitmap();
    ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    bitmap2.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100,stream);
    File file = new File(path);
    FileOutputStream fOut = new FileOutputStream(file);

    bitmap2.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, fOut);
    fOut.flush();
    fOut.close();
```